# Spring Boot Back-End in Hostinger

Tags: java, spring-boot, hosting

necesito subir una aplicación back end hecha en spring boot a hostinger y no se como hacerlo, ya tengo un dominio comprado y un VPS, intente subir la aplicación al directorio raíz luego de hacer clean and build y no funciona de esa forma, intente también subir solo el archivo jar pero tampoco funciona...

Alguien podría ayudarme con alguna guía detallada o algún tutorial?
La aplicación funciona perfectamente n un entorno local y hasta hace un mes la tenia colgada en railway funcionando correctamente.

Desde ya les agradezco mucho la ayuda!

Saludos

Comment: Tienes que desplegar tu aplicación. ¿Tienes el JDK de Java/OpenJDK instalado en el VPS? Tiene memoria suficiente? Cómo "subiste el archivo JAR"? Tienes que ejecutar la aplicación, no se va a desplegar sola. Si tienes más detalles de tu problema, ve a [edit] y responde a todo esto.

Comment: Muchas gracias, si estoy viendo que es un tema, yo acostumbrado a heroku o railway donde todo se realiza automáticamente desde el repo de GitHub...

Comment: voy a intentar hacerlo con esta guia https://www.hostinger.com/tutorials/how-to-install-tomcat-on-ubuntu/

Comment: Una VPS es un servidor. Tendrá un OS y librerías básicas, pero debes hacer todo porque es eso, un servidor. Si te dan una caja con un procesador, un disco y memoria no va a tener tareas automatizadas. ;)